# Jquery Datepicker says object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker' within Jquery calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm trying to use the jquery datepicker and when my code is simply something like this:

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy'
});
```

It works just fine, but when I try to use $(this) or even just $('startDate') again within my call, it throws an "Object doesn't support property or method 'datepicker'" error. (Like in the code below)

```
$('#startDate').datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(2015, 1, 1));
        // Also throws an error when I replace $(this) with $('startDate')
})
```

I even get the same error just by wrapping it in $(document).ready() and still using the simple working version...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#startDate').datepicker({
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'MM yy'
        });
});
```

Any idea what could be causing this error?

**EDIT**

Here is a more full example of what I'm trying to do...

Basically, I would like to be able to toggle a date selector to being a monthpicker and a datepicker based on the value of the variable timeBucket...

The issue is that whenever I use $('#startDate').datepicker within my original $('#startDate').datepicker it throws an error...

`$('#startDate').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: timeBucket == 2 ? 'MM yy' : "mm/dd/yy",
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            if (timeBucket == 2) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $('startDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
            }
        }
    }).focus(function () {
        var thisCalendar = $(this);
        if (timeBucket == 1) {
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').detach();
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css("display", "none");
        } else {
            $('.ui-datepicker-calendar').css("display", "");
        }
    });`

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example of the issue?

Comment: I believe that it happens because the datepicker is still being constructed. Try the defaultDate property [http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate).
Alternatively you can add the following line `$('#startDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2015, 1, 1));`

Comment: `// Also throws an error when I replace $(this) with $('startDate')` Should that be `$('#startDate');`? Not the complete issue, but just something I noticed.

Comment: Should definitely be `$('#startDate')`

Comment: What's the end goal here? You're having a problem (that you've described) when trying to do X, but what is X? If you tell us that we can tell you if you're even close to the right track.

Comment: @Anthony, I've added a more detailed description of what i'm trying to do.

Comment: @Carlos, I just filled in a generic date to show what I was trying to do... Sorry I should have been more clear. I don't think the issue is that the datepicker is still being constructed, since the first call works just fine. It's only the $('#startDate') within the first that throws the error.

Comment: @Tim, Thanks for pointing that out, but that's not the issue that was just a mistake when I was copying it over...

Comment: Thanks for your help everyone... Hopefully this helps... I'll try to create a jsfiddle with the same issue.

Comment: @Coder 101 it is missing a # in your code... you have `$('startDate')` in the `onSelect` and it should be `$('#startDate')`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```js
$("#StartDate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  beforeShow: function() {
    // Everytime datepicker open, this function will run
    //$(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(2015, 1, 1));
  }
});
// Set datetime here once when page load.
$('#StartDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date(2015, 1, 1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />Start:
<input type="text" id="StartDate" />
```

Hope this helps.